# Aligning text to match beginning of another element CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to align text together in a certain way and hoping to make it work responsively as well.

I have this class which centers the div 
 (I was forced to specify a width and height of 50% otherwise it would not center it horizontally or vertically.

I'm trying to get the `<p><span><sup>*</sup>Lorem's sipsum ipsul lo ip lipson loroem</span></p>` aligned left to the `<strong>Loremipsumlo</strong>` (see codepen) http://codepen.io/mhussa19/pen/QjEwXa

The paragraph text should begin with the L of loremipsup

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with out constantly adjusting the top position (when screen size changes) which i don't want to do.

The h1 is position relative and the spans are both position absolute right: 0;. This works well so I wouldn't want to change this. See class setup below

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
}
h1 span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

<div class="jumbo-header">
    <h1>
      <span>Experience</span><span><strong>Loremipsumlo</strong></span>
    </h1>
    <p><span><sup>*</sup>Lorem's sipsum ipsul lo ip lipson loroem</span></p>
 </div>

.jumbo-header {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 38em;
    height: 50%;
    z-index:10;   }
```

Comment: Is it CSS or SCSS? Please be clear.

Comment: I'm more interested in how to do it scss is just what i'm using. It all compiles to css anyways

Comment: Great. Add the relevant tags. `:)`

Comment: alright my apologies

Comment: No, unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only** provide the compiled CSS.  This is not a Sass problem.

Comment: nvm thanks for fixing